# React bootstrap modal not rendering updated data

Tags: reactjs

When I'm running the below code and clicking the "Read" button, data is not updating in modal window even though I have few different components rendered.

I'm new to react, I have read similar posts that it has something to do with changing state but don't really know how to apply it in this case?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import ButtonToolbar from "react-bootstrap/ButtonToolbar";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import CardDeck from "react-bootstrap/CardDeck";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import "./posts.css";

const config = require("../../config").config();
class MyVerticallyCenteredModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            {this.props.title}
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <pre>{this.props.title}</pre>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my parent component where I'm having button opening modal, post.title and post.body is not being updated on modal.

```
  class Posts extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          posts: [],
          modalShow: false
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch(config.localhostPrefix + "/api/stories")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(posts => this.setState({ posts }));
      }
      render() {
        let modalClose = () => this.setState({ modalShow: false });
        return (
          <div className="Posts">
            <h2>Posts</h2>
            <CardDeck>
              {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                <Card key={post._id}>
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>"{post.title}"</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      {post.body}
                      <ButtonToolbar>
                        <Button
                          variant="primary"
                          onClick={() => this.setState({ modalShow: true })}
                        >
                          Read
                        </Button>
                        <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
                          show={this.state.modalShow}
                          title={post.title}
                          body={post.body}
                          onHide={modalClose}
                        />
                      </ButtonToolbar>
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                  <Card.Footer>
                    <Container>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>
                          <small className="text-muted">
                            Created:
                            <Moment format=" YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm">
                              {post.createdAt}
                            </Moment>{" "}
                          </small>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>
                          <small className="text-muted">
                            Updated:
                            <Moment format=" YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm">
                              {post.updatedAt}
                            </Moment>
                          </small>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>
                          <small className="text-muted">
                            Author: {post.author}{" "}
                          </small>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Container>
                  </Card.Footer>
                </Card>
              ))}
            </CardDeck>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Posts;
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this? I'll be interested to take a look at it?

Comment: @JohnKennedy work ongoing.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/j20yvmy40v, so I simplified my code, added mock data, but there are some additional errors that are not allowing it to run properly but maybe this will clarify enough so you will be able to figure my problem.

Comment: Kindly see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for creating the sandbox. I was able to fix the issue you're having. I slightly modified your `Posts` component. You were close but had one or two things you missed out. Please see my changes below:

```
class Posts extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: [
        { _id: 1, title: "title1", body: "body1", author: "author1" },
        { _id: 2, title: "title2", body: "body2", author: "author2" },
        { _id: 3, title: "title3", body: "body3", author: "author3" }
      ],
      postId: null,
      modalShow: false
    };
  }
  modalClose = id => {
    this.setState({ modalShow: !this.state.modalShow, postId: id });
  };
  renderModal = () => {
    const { modalShow, postId, posts } = this.state;
    const post = posts.find(post => (post._id === postId));

    return (
      <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
        show={modalShow}
        title={post.title}
        body={post.body}
        onHide={this.modalClose}
      />
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Posts">
        <h2>Posts</h2>
        <CardDeck>
          {this.state.posts.map(post => (
            <Card key={post._id + post.title}>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>"{post.title}"</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  {post.body}
                  <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button
                      variant="primary"
                      onClick={() => this.modalClose(post._id)}
                    >
                      Read
                    </Button>
                  </ButtonToolbar>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <Container>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <small className="text-muted">
                        Author: {post.author}{" "}
                      </small>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Container>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardDeck>
        {this.state.modalShow && this.renderModal()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

> It is not perfect but something to help you figure out what was wrong initially.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I have run code with your changes, but I still have the initial problem. When I click on button "read" modal show the same data i.e it shows all the time first row regardless which button I click.

Comment: My code doesn't have that behaviour. Clicking read only shows the data associated with the clicked row. You might have missed something while copying.

Comment: Above example based on the mock data generates 3 different squares with button read and different content. When I click any of them the data is not associated with the clicked row.

Comment: I found the issue, in the `renderModal` method, I mistakenly did this: `const post = posts.find(post => (post._id = postId));` instead of this: `const post = posts.find(post => (post._id === postId));` 

Note: the difference is the equality operator `===`.


I made the code slightly better, see here https://codesandbox.io/s/9zvj3v2k64

Comment: Thanks a lot! now it works, I have also cleaned up the sandbox if anyone wants to se clear pic https://codesandbox.io/embed/98n05o13pr.